# Why the output in IPython is not same as in Python?

Tags: python, ipython

In IPython 6.1.0 which Python version is 3.6.2:

> Python 3.6.2 (default, Aug  8 2017, 21:56:47)
>   Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
>   IPython 6.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
>
> In [2]: c = {}
>
> In [3]: c['g'] = 3
>
> In [4]: c['a'] = 1
>
> In [5]: c['c'] = 2
>
> In [6]: c
>
> Out[6]: {'a': 1, 'c': 2, 'g': 3}

and in Python 3.6.2:

> Python 3.6.2 (default, Aug  8 2017, 21:56:47)
>   [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)] on darwin
>   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>
> />>> c = {}
>
> />>> c['g'] = 3
>
> />>> c['a'] = 1
>
> />>> c['c'] = 2
>
> />>> c
>
> {'g': 3, 'a': 1, 'c': 2}

Comment: It is because the pprint is on, and it displays the elements in alphabetical order. You can toggle that with `%pprint`. For 3.6 I think they should change this behaviour though.

Comment: Yeah, I have seen the existing question. Thx